# .Net Core failing to receive XML data

Tags: xml, http, asp.net-core, header, response

Have a method which currently handles 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' as expected. This method is used to handle response from clients we have. A new client sends their response with a content type of 'text/xml'.

Whatever I try the only thing I get is the Request.FormData populated with just one Key containing the first part of the XML and the Value containing the rest of the XML. Request.Body is always empty.

```
   [DontWrapResult]
    public async Task<ActionResult> ResponseAsync(string order, string gateway)
    {
        var orderId = DecodeOrderId(order);
        var authToken = await GetAuthTokenAsync();

        var orderDto = await GetOrderDetailsAsync(orderId, authToken);

        CheckOrderCompleted(orderDto);
        await ClearBasketAsync(orderId, authToken);

        var requestBody = "";
        var contentType = Request.ContentType;
        var length = Request.ContentLength;

        using (var reader = new StreamReader(Request.Body, Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            requestBody = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
        }
```

Suggestions I have seen is to change the Accept type to XML but I have no idea how to do that. The examples just show changing the type in Postman but I don't see how that helps my code.

Please Note I still need this method to accept 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' aswell. If I need to create a new method specifically for the XML response that's fine, but not sure how to set it to specifically accept that type.

Comment: As far as I know, un order to receive and send data from our Web API in XML format, we need to configure the corresponding services in the Startup class. I suggest you could add `services.AddControllers().AddXmlDataContractSerializerFormatters();` in ConfigureServices method.

Comment: @BrandoZhang yeah this is one of the first suggestions I found and it didn't change anything in the Request.

Comment: Do you mean you want this api method could receive both xml or formdata as the request type?

Comment: Correct, if this is not possible I don't mind having to create 2 separate methods but how do you then determine what receives what?

Comment: @BrandoZhang ^^^